# Onclick at an icon inside a form

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I want to add an icon inside a form and be able to click it and run javascript code once clicked.Basically,i know how to add the icon on the form but i don't know how to make it clickable with OnClick.

the input code for the text field is
HTML Code:

```
<input id="cool"
   style=" width:45%; padding:4px; padding-right:25px;" type="text" name="game">
```

and the css code for the icon

CSS Code:

```
#cool {
    background: url(game.jpg) no-repeat scroll 448px -1px;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

But i don't know as i said where i should place OnClick command in order to make only the icon clickable.

Comment: Adding onclick is easy: `<input onclick="alert(1)" />`.

Comment: yes but in this case i want only the icon to be clicked not the whole text field.

Comment: Do it the hard way using `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent; or create a clickable layer over the text box.

Comment: Can you explain what is "make only the icon clickable"? This is a text input, not button input or a button.

Answer (score 1):

3 ways to do this:

1. using

   ```
   <input type='text' id='input'>
   ```

   with a bg image and

   ```
   $("#input").click(function(e){if(e.pageX > start_x && e.pageX < end_x && e.pageY > start_y && e.pageY < end_y){
       // open new page
   }});
   ```
2. using this:

   ```
   <div style='position:relative'>
           <input />
           <div style='width:20px;height:20px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0' onclick="//js code to open page"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. using this code:

   ```
   <div>
           <div class='left'></div>
           <div class='right'><input /></div>
   </div>
   <style>
           .left{float:left;width:25px;height:25px;background-image:url(the_image.png)}
           .right{float:left;width:200px;height:25px;}
   </style>
   ```